# Why can't I expose a Plane variable in my unity script?

Tags: unity

I've got a script which creates raycasts. I wanted to use the (presumably less expensive) Plane.Raycast rather than the GameObject.Collider.Raycast (because the gameobject one has a distance parameter so that's one more check)

I can expose the plane gameobject in my scene easily by simply making a public gameobject variable like this:

```
public GameObject floor;
```

however when I turn it into this:

```
public Plane floor;
```

It doesn't expose in the scene. Why is this?

Comment: Same thing happened to me yesterday.  The Plane struct isn't the game thing as a GameObject Plane; it's a geometric representation of a plane used for math calculations.  [Plane docs.](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Plane.html)

Answer (score 3):

It's because the only things that show up in the inspector are serializable fields or things that you implement in `OnInspectorGUI` as a custom editor for that class.

For reference: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/SerializeField

> **Serializable types are:**
>
> - All classed inheriting from UnityEngine.Object, for example Gameobject, Commponent, MonoBehaviour, Texture2D, AnimationClip..
> - All basic data types like int, string, float, bool.
> - Some built in types like Vector2, Vector3, Vector4, Quaternion, Matrix4x4, Color, Rect, Layermask...
> - Arrays of a serializable type
> - List of a serializable type (new in Unity2.6)
> - Enums
>
> Headsup note: if you put one element in a list (or array) twice, when the list gets serialized, you'll get two copies of that element, instead of one copy being in the new list twice.

Now `Plane` is just a struct that has a `Vector3` and a `float`, so you could use those two serializable types to construct a `Plane` object at runtime if you really need to.

But my guess is that you really want to leave the serialized field as `GameObject` so you can point to the plane in the scene.